# Android MediaPlayer OnPreparedListener

Tags: android, media

I am working on a simple app and using a MediaPlayer to play some background noise in 1 activity. I am reading up on MediaPlayer and am not sure whether or not to implement an OnPreparedListener to trigger the start() method. What are the pros / cons to each approach?

Approach 1:

```
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound);
    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mediaPlayer.start();
```

Approach 2:

```
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound);
    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As per the docs, calling `start()` is effective when you are playing locally available resources for which the `MediaPlayer` does not require to fetch the data and process it for playing. For example playing audio resources from raw folder.

If you are trying to play a resource from remote source, its a better practice to go for `OnPreparedListener()` because it might involve fetching and decoding media data.

So, if you know for sure, that your resource is locally available and is of short length, go for `Approach 1`. Otherwise `Approach 2` would be suitable.

Ideally, I prefer this.

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri);
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){

@Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
    }
});
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

The `MediaPlayer` has always been tricky for me to work with. So, I would recommend you to start with the [developer docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html). Go through it, understand the state diagram. I am sure it will help you in solving lot of questions which you are yet to come across.

Comment: My resources are all local for now (R.raw), but can you clarify what you mean by "if you know for sure, that your resource is locally available and is of short length". How short does the resource need to be to GUARENTEE that the resource is going to work with directly calling start()?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you are playing a video from `internet`. If you start directly the player it would crash because it may be not ready to play because of some `internet` problems or something else. But if you use `preparedlistener` then it will not start the player until it is ready to play.

Therefore it is good to have `onpreparedlistener` so your activity does not crash or misbehaves.