# Android: How get media player if prepared?

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I use `media player`

I want if `media player` is prepared , play button is visible and if not prepared not visible this button

Comment: what did you tried ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android MediaPlayer OnPreparedListener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827190/android-mediaplayer-onpreparedlistener)

Answer (score 1):

Just use **[MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener.html)**

> Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when the media
> source is ready for playback.

#### Example

```
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){

@Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
       // Media source is ready for 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to set media player state:

```
boolean mMediaPlayerPrepared; // make it global

public void setIsMediaPlayerPrepared(boolean prepared) {
    mMediaPlayerPrepared = prepared;
}
```

And set it from `OnPreparedListener`

```
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    setIsMediaPlayerPrepared(true);
}
});
```

Use this method to get the state of media player:

```
public boolean isMediaPlayerPrepared() {
    return mMediaPlayerPrepared;
}
```

Check prepared state by calling `isMediaPlayerPrepared` method wherever you want to and do the stuff.

Comment: Need to setIsMediaPlayerPrepared(false) once it has been reset or sth right?