# I need to implement audio from my own res/raw files in recyclerview for each item

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I can't figure out how to implement mediaplayer to do play sound for each TITLE within Recyclerview : press on a row play the sound, prew another row stop the previous one and play the new one. I want same for the child layout to.

My adapter:

```
class RecAdapter(private val list: List<Movie>?) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecAdapter.RecViewHolder>() {


    var previousExpandedPosition = -1
        internal set

    internal var mExpandedPosition = -1

    fun getmExpandedPosition(): Int {
        return mExpandedPosition
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater
            .from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.item_movie, parent, false)
        return RecViewHolder(view)


    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val movie = list!![position]

        holder.bind(movie)

        val isExpanded = position == mExpandedPosition
        holder.subItem.visibility = if (isExpanded) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE


        if (isExpanded)
            previousExpandedPosition = position
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            mExpandedPosition = if (isExpanded) -1 else position

            notifyDataSetChanged()

        }


    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list?.size ?: 0
    }

    inner class RecViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        private val title: TextView
        private val genre: TextView
        val subItem: View

        init {

            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_title)
            genre = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sub_item_genre)

            subItem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sub_item)
        }



        fun bind(movie: Movie) {


            title.text = movie.title
            genre.text = "Genre: " + movie.genre

        }
    }

}
```

Main activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val movieList = ArrayList<Movie>()

        movieList.add(Movie("Schindler's List", "Biography, Drama, History"))
        movieList.add(Movie("Pulp Fiction", "Crime, Drama"))
        movieList.add(Movie("No Country for Old Men", "Crime, Drama, Thriller"))
        movieList.add(Movie("Léon: The Professional", "Crime, Drama, Thriller"))
        movieList.add(Movie("Fight Club", "Drama"))
        movieList.add(Movie("Forrest Gump ", "Drama, Romance"))
        movieList.add(Movie("The Shawshank Redemption", "Crime, Drama"))
        movieList.add(Movie("The Godfather", "Crime, Drama"))
        movieList.add(Movie("A Beautiful Mind", "Biography, Drama"))
        movieList.add(Movie("Schindler's List2", "Biography, Drama, History"))
        movieList.add(Movie("Pulp Fiction2", "Crime, Drama"))
        movieList.add(Movie("No Country for Old Men2", "Crime, Drama, Thriller"))
        movieList.add(Movie("Léon: The Professional2", "Crime, Drama, Thriller"))
        movieList.add(Movie("Fight Club2", "Drama"))
        movieList.add(Movie("Forrest Gump2 ", "Drama, Romance"))
        movieList.add(Movie("The Shawshank Redemption2", "Crime, Drama"))
        movieList.add(Movie("The Godfather2", "Crime, Drama"))
        movieList.add(Movie("A Beautiful Mind2", "Biography, Drama"))





        val adapter= RecAdapter(movieList)




        val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recview)




        recyclerView!!.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL))






        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
    }
}
```

and the class:

```
class Movie(val title: String, val genre: String, val sound: String) {

}
```

I tried everything with and no results.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ikeaMYq     https://imgur.com/a/kTwBLAU

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android MediaPlayer OnPreparedListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827190/android-mediaplayer-onpreparedlistener)

Comment: not the same with "Possible duplicate of Android MediaPlayer OnPreparedListener"......